# Approaching companies for student vacation work

Tags: applications

I am a third year electronic engineering undergraduate student. I'd like to gain some practical experience in the workplace through vacation work (be it paid or even unpaid if the company cannot offer remuneration).

From past experience and searches I have noticed that companies in my country do not generally advertise such opportunities on jobseeking websites.

My question is therefore what is the appropriate way to approach companies for student vacation work (email, telephone, direct visit?) and is it acceptable to do so?

How do companies, especially in the engineering and software fields, feel about employment of students over vacation periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of work it helps to have a direct contact. Often the decision about bringing in interns or any kind of short-term university-student help is made directly by a department supervisor, rather than the Human Resources apparatchiks.

Ask around: ask your fellow students where they have worked summers. Ask recent graduates about where they work. If they speak well of the place, ask them to send an introductory email both to you and the supervisor saying "Hello, Blargian is a fellow student of mine. I told him about your company, and he's interested in working with you next summer." Then you can follow up by sending your information.

Answer (score 1):

Apply to the companies, if they have a post you may be lucky, if not, then the application may end up in the bin, with or without a reply...

For your second question, some companies welcome them, others don't...